# Secure local database or service

Tags: encryption, databases

I’m trying to secure a database of questions and I wonder if it’s actually possible.

There are 2 ways the client (mobile App) can get questions:

1. Local DB within the app.
2. Service that returns questions

I can encrypt the questions in the local DB using AES for example, but then the client will need the key to decrypt the questions.

If I use a service, then a client can just make multiple calls and get the entire DB overtime.

Seems to me that no matter which approach I choose a determined hacker/developer can overcome it.

Are there any techniques to handle this kind of scenario or is it a waste of time trying?

Comment: So, by "secure" you mean that you do not want users to be able to obtain the full set of questions that they are entitled to ... or rather, you want to control when and how they obtain the questions. I'm not sure that this is actually about security, but DRM.

Comment: I actually don't want competitors to still the questions and create copycat apps.

Comment: But to do that, you need to limit the people who have legitimate access. I'm not sure this is possible. You could make a copycat StackExchange by stealing all the questions and answers. You need to make your app more than just the content. Once you serve the content, anyone can steal it. You need to look at why your app is more than just the questions.